# whats wrong with this? its not starting the service after 5 minutes..Rather its sending after 1 min only

Tags: android

This should start the service after 5 minutes but its starting after 1 minute

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundDataSender.class);  
            PendingIntent piHeartBeatService = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(piHeartBeatService);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (5*60*1000) , piHeartBeatService);
```

Comment: Please use the formatting options available. Also, 'y' is not a word

Answer (score 0):

You should write :

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    System.currentTimeMillis() + (5*60*1000),
    (5*60*1000) ,
    piHeartBeatService);
```

if you want your alarm to start in 5 minutes (and repeat each 5 minutes afterward)...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL=300000;


Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),UPDATE_INTERVAL,pendingIntent);
```